# Should i unbind before bind?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I would like to programmatically bind in `NSTextField` and change it at runtime. I have e question. Do I need unbind before new bind?
for example:

```
[_noteTextField bind:@"value" toObject:self withKeyPath:@"project.saveNote" options:nil];
[_noteTextField unbind:@"value"];
[_noteTextField bind:@"value" toObject:self withKeyPath:@"project.note" options:nil];
```

Is it correct? Or maybe i don't need unbind

```
[_noteTextField bind:@"value" toObject:self withKeyPath:@"project.saveNote" options:nil];
[_noteTextField bind:@"value" toObject:self withKeyPath:@"project.note" options:nil];
```

Comment: @matt do yo have a link to this warning?

Comment: Use `NSValueBinding` instead of `@"value"`. Why do you want to change a binding? It feels like a design flaw.

Comment: @Willeke Even I would prefer to replace the object on controller level instead of changing the binding, it might be useful. At least `-unbind:` exists.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple values bindings, especially for boolean values like `enabled`. These are implemented through changing the key for the bound property, i. e. `enabled`, `enabled2`, … Therefore even this multi-value bindings remove an existing binding, if you use the same key twice.

However, it is not documented, whether a existing binding is removed and therefore an implementation can chose a different behavior.

Why don't you want to explicitly remove an existing binding? This is, what you want to do. And it is a good idea to have code that explicitly says, what it wants to do.